# Finding the basis of the null space for $y''''=a^4y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm attempting to prove that for $$y''''=a^4y, y(0)=0, y'(0)=0, y(L)=0, y'(L)=0$$
to have a nontrivial solution, we must have that $\cos(aL)\cosh(aL)=1$.

I've been given a hint, that is to prove that the null space of this this D.E. is $[\sin(ax),\cos(ax),\sinh(ax),\cosh(ax)]$.  I began by substituting $y=e^{mx}$ and found a basis of $[e^{ax},e^{-ax},\cos(ax),\sin(ax)]$.  I'm thinking that to get $\sinh(ax), \cosh(ax)$ in my null space I would need to use their exponential forms, ie, $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$, but I'm unsure how to proceed in proving this, as well as how I would need to use this to prove that $\cos(aL)\cosh(aL)=1$ for a nontrivial solution.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to use the basis $y_1=\sin(ax)$, $y_2=\cos(ax)$, $y_3=\sinh(ax)$, $y_4=\cosh(ax)$.

Let $y=\sum_{j=1}^4 c_jy_j$. Use $y(0)=0$ to show $c_2+c_4=0$. Use $y'(0)=0$ to show $c_1+c_3=0$. Now $y=c_1(\sin(ax)-\sinh(ax))+c_2(\cos(ax)-\cosh(ax))$. Lay out the system of linear equations

$$0=y(L)=c_1(\sin(aL)-\sinh(aL))+c_2(\cos(aL)-\cosh(aL))$$
$$0=y'(L)=c_1(\cos(aL)-\cosh(aL))+c_2(-\sin(aL)-\sinh(aL)).$$

It has a nontrivial solution, so the determinant must vanish. Compute it and you're done.

Comment: Which determinant precisely are you speaking of?  The Wronskian? Or with $y(0), y'(0), y(L), y'(L)$?

Comment: The determinant of this system of linear equations in the variables $c_1$ and $c_2$. It is $(\sin(aL)-\sinh(aL))(-\sin(aL)-\sinh(aL))-(\cos(aL)-\cosh(aL)^2$. It's messy, but comes out as $2-2\cos(aL)\cosh(aL)$, which you set to 0 to show the result.

Answer (score 0):

Factor the associaated polynomial, $\lambda^4 -1 = (\lambda -1 )(\lambda + 1)(\lambda^1 + 1).$

You get the four functions $y_1 = e^x$, $y^2 = e^{-x}$, $y_3 = \cos(x)$, $y_4 = 
\sin(x).$   These span the solution space of your ODE.

You can also use $\cosh(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ instead of the exponentials because the transformation $(e^x, e^{-x})\mapsto(\cosh(x), \sinh(x))$ is an invertible one.

Comment: I already put in my question that I know these to be the solutions, but I'm unsure how to proceed with showing $\cosh(ax),\sinh(ax)$ are part of the basis.  Is it as simple as saying that $\cosh(ax),\sinh(ax)$ are linear combinations of $e^{ax}, e^{-ax}$?

Comment: Yes, and vice versa. That's all folks.